# Why can't I edit a raised flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, retracted-flags

I raised a flag for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017683/how-do-i-convert-text-into-phonemes). When I raised the flag, the question looked like a bot text without any specific question, so I raised an `unclear what the question is` flag. Then the OP edited it to a question, that is imho way too broad. So I retracted my flag to raise the appropriate `question is too broad` flag. But now the system tells me that I can't raise a flag, because I retracted it. Is there a reason for this behaviour? Either I look stupid for raising something that the moderator will perceive as a random flag or no flag will be raised at all. Why can't I update the reason for a flag, when the OP edits the question?

Comment: Not a duplicate imho. I don't vote on close, I raise a flag. And though I do understand the problem of voting/flag raising sheenanigans - I simply want to change the reason for flagging a question. For the reasons explained in my question - that either the moderator will think that I am irresponsible for raising the flag or no flag will be raised, because I retracted the flag.